# No log handling enabled - turning on stderr logging Cannot find

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to setup a Cron Job that runs a .php file that will automate client email correspondance. I've created the .php file and the Cron Job through cPanel. Everything works fine in that I'm getting my test email as I require it when I require it but I'm also getting an additional server email on every send with the following content;

> No log handling enabled - turning on stderr logging Cannot find module (MTA-MIB): At line 1 in (none) Cannot find module (NETWORK-SERVICES-MIB): At line 1 in (none)

The Cron Job is as follows;

> 0.3 * * * * php -q /home/USERNAME/public_html/cron/test.php

I've done research on this site adn could find a solution. I've also chatted with my hosting company and believe it or not his best advice was to refer me to this site.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you run your script from the command line and does it give the same errors ?

Comment: It seems related to SNMP. Which distro are you running?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No log handling enabled - turning on stderr logging Cannot find](http://serverfault.com/questions/299970/no-log-handling-enabled-turning-on-stderr-logging-cannot-find)

Answer (score 2):

There's a good chance you're a customer of yet another clueless hosting provider. That error or should I say warning is a spit out from php that they have the php-snmp library compiled in but their MIBs are not mapping correctly. They need to fix their snmp install and they will go away.

It is not your problem.. it is theirs.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your response. I originally thought it was their config issue so I'll head back to them with a little more emphasis this time.